# How do I trap in a bash script and guarantee execution?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script like this

```
#!/bin/sh

function cleanup() {
  osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" -e "set current settings of window 1 to settings set \"HomeBrew\"" -e "end tell"
}

trap cleanup EXIT
trap cleanup SIGTERM
trap cleanup SIGUSR1
trap cleanup SIGPIPE

osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\"" -e "set background color of window 1 to {5000, 0, 20000}" -e "end tell"

ssh remote-machine
```

The idea is to change the background color of my terminal when I ssh to remote-machine so I know, at a glance, which machine I'm interacting with. It works. If I exit from ssh via `exit` or `ctrl-d` it works. If I shut down the remote-machine I see "...Broken Pipe" and it works. But, when I leave it overnight, with my Mac's lid closed, I come back in the morning with this message;

```
❯ F0817 16:05:00.031721       1 helper.go:459] read tcp [2xxx:0:1000:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx]:62147->[64:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx]:443: read: no route to host
     client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

And `cleanup` has not run (the terminal is still blue)

What trap am I missing or how to do set trap (or something) so that `cleanup` always runs on exit of this script?

Comment: Try adding `SIGHUP` to the trap.  You can also do this on one line `trap cleanup EXIT  SIGTERM SIGKILL etc.`

Comment: No luck, changed it to `trap cleanup EXIT SIGHUP SIGTERM SIGUSR1 SIGPIPE`. It still failed to run `cleanup` overnight when it disconnected.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not do this in iTerm2.  It handles dynamic profiles (like what you want to accomplish) quite easily.

Comment: @Allan, thanks for the suggestion. It's not clear to me how dynamic profiles in iTerm2 help this case. Do you know of an example?

Comment: I create a profile for each type of server I connect to that profile actually changes the background image to help me identify what server I am connected to (Beastie for FreeBSD, a shimmery Apple for Macs, etc.). You can do the same with color.  When I connect/disconnect to any of these hosts, it switches the background exactly like how you're trying to accomplish it with a script.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, found it [here](https://iterm2.com/documentation-automatic-profile-switching.html). It wasn't at all clear from [these docs](https://iterm2.com/documentation-dynamic-profiles.html)

Comment: Awesome.  Sorry for using the wrong term.  The Profile switching will accomplish what you’re setting out to do.

Comment: @Allan, FYI, iTerm2 screwed up the the similar ways. I setup the profile stuff on various machines and it worked, switching profiles when I sshed in and switching back ... until it didn't. Left a machine on ssh, closed the lid, opened next day, ssh had disconnected, iTerm2 had not switched back. So unfortunately iTerm2 wasn't really a solution for me